# Empty but styled div in 960.gs

Tags: css, grid, 960.gs

I have the following column in my webpage draft, which is based on HTML5 Boilerplate and 960.gs:

```
<div class="grid_2" style="background-color:black;" />
```

However, when I open the page in Chrome, the column doesn't show up at all, unless I put some kind of content in it, like text or whitespace.

How can I make this work without resorting to desperate solutions like `&thinsp;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `div` without content doesn't display because there is no height being inherited from content. If you want it to show up--you need to specify a height of some sort... or just use `&nbsp;`

```
<div class="grid_2" style="background-color:black;">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="grid_2" style="background-color:black;height:20px"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support IE5.5 or IE6, you can use the CSS2 `min-width` property to specify the smallest width you want the column to have.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would try adding a closing tag, since I don't think that is valid HTML:

```
<div class="grid_2" style="background-color:black;"></div>
```